# Can't print filepath of all files on all drives

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

My code in order till the line.

```
drives = [ chr(x) + ":\\" for x in range(65,91) if os.path.exists(chr(x) + ":\\") ]
```

I see all the extentions of files in a specified disk with this code block

```
ListFiles = os.walk("d:\\") #normally putting drives here. and getting an error.
SplitTypes = []
for walk_output in ListFiles:
    for file_name in walk_output[-1]:
        SplitTypes.append(file_name.split(".")[-1])

print(SplitTypes)
```

with this

```
counter = 0
inp = 'txt' #normally putting SplitTypes here and getting error 
for drive in drives: # drops every .txt file that 
    for r, d, f in os.walk(drive): #It can get in every disk 
        for file in f:             #(first block) get's every disk's available on system
            filepath = os.path.join(r, file)
            if inp in file: #this line find's every file that ends with .txt
                counter += 1 #this line add's one and goes to the next one
                print(os.path.join(r, file)) #every file' location gets down by down        
print(f"counted {counter} files.") #this line finally gives the count number
```

---

Second code block prints out all the file's extentions such as: txt, png, exe, dll, etc.
Example:

```
['epr',itx', 'itx', 'ilut', 'itx', 'itx', 'cube', 'cube', 'cube', 'itx', 'cube', 'cube''js','dll', 'dll', 'dll', 'json', 'json', 'json', 'json', 'json', 'json', 'json', 'json', 'json', 'json''rar', 'rar', 'ini', 'chm', 'dll', 'dll', 'dll', 'exe', 'sfx', 'sfx', 'exe', 'exe', 'ion', 'txt', 'txt', 'txt', 'exe', 'txt', 'txt', 'txt', 'txt', 
'txt', 'txt', 'txt',]
```

The problem I'm facing here is I can't scan for extensions in all drivers (second block of code).
And I can't search all the files with the extensions that (second block of code) provided to third block of code

Comment: OK. *Why* exactly can't you scan for extensions in all drives? What's stopping you?

Comment: check the third block inp = SplitTypes but Can't print out the extentions that 2nd block provided to third block It normally should print out file locations of those file's when I type inp='txt' and comment out second block there is no problem prints out all the locations of files that ends with .txt but I want to print out every extention.

Comment: Also If you take a look at the last block of code you will see that extentions are repating maybe we should first get rid of the repeating values there?

Comment: `SplitTypes` is a *list* of file extensions (with possibly many repeats). So I am not sure what you think the `if inp in file:` does because it will always be `False` (and getting rid of the duplicates wouldn't fix that). It's unclear what the purpose of getting all the extensions in first place was because in the second block *of course* the extension of the current file will be in ``SplitTypes` since it's a list of every one seen.

Comment: comment out third block and run second block as it is displayed you will get the last block

Comment: I understand what the first two block of code do. I don't understand what you are trying to do in the third block. Block two will find the extension of *every* file on the drives. It's not clear what you are trying to with this list of all file extensions.

Comment: I'm trying to use those extentions to find all the files in the disk with the third block check the third block now edited

Comment: To find files with single kind of extension, the edited block three makes more sense. What still does **not** make sense is trying to use the list of extensions in `SplitTypes` which has all the extensions found on all of the drives for `inp` — so very file's extension will be in that list.

Comment: then How can I scan a disk scanRecurse? I dont want to get folders I just want to get files

Comment: Or create a for loop with os.listdir()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will print the full filepath to every file on every disk of your Windows system. Note that it may take a very long time to finish.

```
import os

drives = [chr(x) + ":\\" for x in range(65,91) if os.path.exists(chr(x) + ":\\")]

counter = 0
for drive in drives:
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(drive):
        for file in files:
            print(os.path.join(root, file))
        counter += len(files)

print(f"counted {counter} files.")
```

Comment: than you so much ! Thats what I was looking for

Comment: But I still have a problem this only took 5 minutes but Im not sure if it found everything When I search for .png I cant see any In there How can I verify that this is actually working?

Comment: There is no reason it would skip .png (or any other kind of) files. To make testing easier, the elements of the `drives` list can be changed to be specific directories on specific drives: i.e. `drives = [r'c:\testdirs\dir1', r'd:\path\to\another\dir`, etc...]`.

Comment: This Didn't get every file I got more than 800.000 file's counted with batch script just in c:\ if you put the d:\ also it will be well over a million when I run this it just prints out 600.000 in both drives

Comment: As I said, I know of no reason for any files to be skipped.

Answer (score 0):

Ok done! Here's how it's done remove the second block no needed 
This Will go through every available disks and files 
correct me If anything doesn't make sense here I'm still a python newbie

```
counter = 0
inp = []
for drive in drives:
    for r, d, f in os.walk(drive):
        for file in f:
            filepath = os.path.join(r, file)
            for inp in os.listdir(drive):
                if inp in file:
                    counter += 1
                    print(os.path.join(r, file))           
print(f"counted {counter} files.")
```

Comment: I agree that you don't need second block. However this code does not work either. The `if inp in file:` still makes no sense and would only ever be `True` if a file happens to contain the name of the directory it is in (i.e. `J:\Thunderbird\Profiles\bob\dictionarysearchThunderbird3Overlay.xul`).

Comment: I think you need to explain what you are trying to accomplish in the block of code — it doesn't seem to have anything to do with the title of the question.

Comment: I want to find every folder in disk and search for all the files